# Is there a way to enable VNC on my Pi with python?

Tags: python, vnc

I am creating a system and I want to make it as quick and painless to deploy as possible. 
I also need people who are unfamiliar with RPi to deploy it. So I am creating an installer that can handle all of the first time setup for each pi. One of the things that I need is for VNC to be enabled. I realize it is super simple to do, but its one more thing id like to automate if possible.

How can I enable VNC using python?

I'm also open to using a .sh script or doing something to the config files before raspian is installed, as long as I can copy and paste onto multiple SD cards for deployment. I don't want the deployers to have to go into settings to enable VNC server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Raspbian and want to enable the built-in RealVNC service mode server, you can do this using the systemctl command:

```
systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced
```

which will enable the service so it will start on the next boot. If you want the VNC Server to start *immediately* you should also run:

```
systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced
```

You can call these from Python using subprocess.call()