# Enable VNC Before First Boot

Tags: raspbian-stretch, vnc

Is there a config file that I can edit so that the pi starts with VNC enabled? I'm currently using raspbian stretch as an OS, and VNC works out of the box. The only thing I have to do is enable it from raspi-config. I use real vnc viewer on Fedora 29. Can I just put a file in /boot/ just like with ssh? My goal here is to make the pi boot up for the first time with vnc enabled.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Related (but not a dupe): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90086/19949 (requires access to `/` prior to deployment, as in, does not work by just doing something in `/boot`).

Comment: Are you saying that I can't do it like I would with ssh, or just that it won't work only for that person's case?

Comment: I am just saying that there is "out-of-the-box" no mechanism in place to do the same thing with vnc compared to ssh (have it activated by just putting a file in `/boot`). So you need to have access to `/` (not a FAT partition) to enable vnc.

Comment: Okay, so what do I have to do? And is the root partition `/` always in a separate partition from the `boot` partition?